# Scale of measurements in sign test and signed rank test

Tags: scales, sign-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

Can some one help me to understand the right scale of measurement to use in sign test as well as in signed rank test?

I read a certain book it says nominal scale is used in sign test while ordinal scale is used in the signed rank test, the other online material says ordinal scale is used in both sign test and signed rank test. I'm confused.

Comment: Could you indicate which book/online material offers such distinction?

Answer (score 4):

(Moving comment to answer)

Strictly, the signed rank test is designed to be used on continuous random variables, since you need to be able to rank the differences, and in the usual tables the different arrangements of signs to ranks are assumed to be equally probable under the null.

If the original data that form pairs are only ordinal, it's not really possible to assign ranks (what's the relative ranking of "High minus medium" vs "medium minus low"?)

The sign test arguably also assumes continuity, but if the proper account is made of ties, it can be adapted to deal with ordinal data.

Comment: wouldn't we need at least interval scaled values to properly apply a one-sample signed-rank test (with some correction for ties)? Looking at the test statistic I'd say ordinal alone is not enough to properly rank absolute differeces.

Comment: @MichaelM If you have paired ordinal data, you can't do a signed rank test (without additional assumptions at least), but that's the case I discuss in the last sentence -- where I say "it's not really possible to assign ranks".

Comment: That's clear. But I meant the one-sample case where I test symmetry around some hypothesized location. Is the argument like "if a test for symmetry around $\mu_o$ makes sense, then ordinal is sufficient"?

Comment: It would require additional assumptions; you can do more than in the paired case (since you can certainly get partial ordering for the ones above $\mu_0$ and you can also do it below $\mu_0$ -- the problem comes when you try to rank the absolute differences.). Well, I agree with you; I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

simple sign test use nominal scale data while signed rank test uses ordinal scale data. i am a stats major student and i am currently studying these tests. I hope your confusion is cleared.

for more info consult these books

chahudary, S.M. and kamal, S. (2010), " intorduction to statistical theory" part 1 &2, 8th ed., ilmi kitab khana, Lahore, Pakistan

walpole, R.E., Myers, R.H. and Myers, S.L (2011, " Probability and statistics for engineers and scientist" 9th ed., Prentice Hall, NY